# JIRA Rest API not returning all results

Tags: jira, agile, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api, jira-agile

I am using the JIRA Rest API Calls to fetch in JIRA Agile related metrics such as RapidViews, Sprints, Velocity Charts etc.

I am able to execute the API's using the REST Client, but I do not get all the results and get only limited results.

For ex: this call lists all the sprints for a  particular rapidview , but only the limited results

https://puma.companyname.com/jira/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprintquery/359?maxResults=10000

Could you help me tweak this call to show all sprints for a particular rapidview

Thanks in advance
Adithya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JIRA API will not load all results. It will give it to you in chunks of small results. If there are lots of records then JIRA will send you it in chunk of 50 with one flag named "**isLast**" which carries value either **true** or **false**.

**True** means : There are no more records to be fetched

**False** means : Yes, there are more records to be fetched but that will be provided to you only if you want via more REST requests.

So on the basis of this, you have to run a loop with more API calls to fetch all the results from JIRA database.

You can learn more about this topic over [Here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/)

For Agile API you can use this [resource](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/cloud/)